# What type of Fuel does a 2007 f150 v6 4.2L take?

Tags: ford, gasoline, f-150

What type of Fuel does a 2007 f150 v6 4.2L take? The vehicle did not come with a manual, and I need to refuel.

I contacted the Ford dealership they say they will get back to me. They have not yet. I also contacted the Ford company via Facebook and sent me to a generic place with generic information about f150s for the year of 2007. However who knows if it is for v6 4.2L engines. I'm afraid to put the wrong fuel in my vehicle which might destroy my engine.

Any advice would be nice. Thank You.

Comment: https://owner.ford.com/tools/account/how-tos/owner-manuals-search-results.html?make=Ford&model=F-150&year=2007                                                                                            Google is your best friend...

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Are you wanting to know if it is gasoline or diesel?

Comment: Look I'm just asking is it recommended to put in unleaded or leaded ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of hunting round Google suggests that they're tuned for 87 octane unleaded. You mention unleaded/leaded in your comment - it will have to be unleaded as leaded petrol has been banned for nearly 20 years (unless you live in Algeria, where it was phased out in 2017)

I don't know if it's the same in North America, but most vehicles here have a little sticker on the inside of the fuel filler cover with the fuel requirements on - usually colour coded as well, black for Diesel, green for Unleaded

Answer (score 1):

You MUST USE UNLEADED FUEL ON ANY VEHICLE WITH A CATALYTIC CONVERTOR.  ANY  car or truck (or motorcycle) uses regular unleaded except for performance vehicles like Corvette, performance Mustangs, new HP Mopars, Ferraris, and so on.  Harley Davidson motorcycles also use premium as the Motor Company requires.